# What is the proper evaluation order when assigning a value in a map?

Tags: c++, c++14

I know that compiler is usually the last thing to blame for bugs in a code, but I do not see any other explanation for the following behaviour of the following C++ code (distilled down from an actual project):

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

int main()
{
    auto values = { 1, 3, 5 };
    std::map<int, int> valMap;

    for (auto const & val : values) {
        std::cout << "before assignment: valMap.size() = " << valMap.size();
        valMap[val] = valMap.size();
        std::cout << " -> set valMap[" << val << "] to " << valMap[val] << "\n";
    }
}
```

The expected output of this code is:

```
before assignment: valMap.size() = 0 -> set valMap[1] to 0
before assignment: valMap.size() = 1 -> set valMap[3] to 1
before assignment: valMap.size() = 2 -> set valMap[5] to 2
```

However, when I build a Release version with the (default) C++14 compiler, the output becomes:

```
before assignment: valMap.size() = 0 -> set valMap[1] to 1
before assignment: valMap.size() = 1 -> set valMap[3] to 2
before assignment: valMap.size() = 2 -> set valMap[5] to 3
```

In other words, all values in `valMap` are larger by 1 than what they should be - it looks like the map gets appended before the right-hand-side of the assignment is evaluated.

This happens only in a Release build with C++14 language standard (which is the default in VS2019). Debug builds work fine (I hate when this happens - it took me hours to find out what is going on), as do Release builds of C++17 and C++20. This is why it looks like a bug to me.

My question is: is this a compiler bug, or am I doing something wrong/dangerous by using `.size()` in the assignment?

Comment: I don't think the order of execution of `valMap[val]` and `valMap.size();` is specified in c++14, I think it did change in c++17 which is why changing the C++ standard fixes the problem

Comment: Mutating a value and accessing the value in the same statement is hard to reason about.  And, as discovered, can run afoul of debug versus optimizer.  Even in C++17 where the behavior is specified, it is still hard to reason about and may not do what is intended (especially as inferred by maintainers).  I recommend avoiding this kind of coding style, and break it out to separate statements.  Code for the maintainers, which may be your future self.

Comment: Interesting, I did not know that (obviously). I checked and using insert or emplace makes the problem go away. Can you post it as an answer, so I can accept it?

Comment: @Eljay: would a one-liner using `insert` or `emplace` be better? I guess that the problem with the original code is that the `[]` operator has to be evaluated first, to find what it should do (assign vs. insert) - which is not the case with implicit `insert` or `emplace`...

Comment: No, because even the one-liner that is mutating and accessing the value in the same statement is hard to reason about.  Use two statements, properly ordered for the intended behavior.  Unless you are trying to write [unmaintainable code](https://github.com/Droogans/unmaintainable-code).

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The evaluation order of `A = B` was not specified before c++17, after c++17 `B` is guaranteed to be evaluated before `A`, see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order rule 20.

The behaviour of `valMap[val] = valMap.size();` is therefore unspecified in c++14, you should use:

```
auto size = valMap.size();
valMap[val] = size;
```

Or avoid the problem by using `emplace` which is more explicit than relying on `[]` to automatically insert a value if it doesn't already exist:

```
valMap.emplace(val, size);
```

Comment: Coming from more modern languages, this realization boggled my mind for a bit, the fact that `valMap[2] = SomeFunctionThatThrows();` can actually mutate the map with < C++17.

Comment: Interestingly, the classic `a[i] = i++;` is now *defined* behaviour!

Comment: The linked page says `a[i] = i++;       // undefined behavior until C++17`, though.

Comment: Ah, for scalar types only though